# EF Inserting/Updating navigational properties vs assigning Id's performance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, devart

Let's assume we have a **model/database tables** like below (not well laid out but fits my question). Let's also assume one movie has always only one director and one producer.

**Genre**

- Id
- Name

**SubGenre**

- Id
- Name
- GenreId
- Genre (navigational property)

**Director**

- Id
- Name
- `List<Movie>` (navigational property)

**Producer**

- Id
- Name
- `List<Movie>` (navigational property)

**Actors**

- Id
- Name
- `List<Movie>` (there is many-many table in db) (navigational property)

**Movie**

- Id
- Name
- SubGenreId
- DirectorId
- ProducerId
- `List<Actor>` (navigational property)
- Director (navigational property)
- Producer (navigational property)
- SubGenre (navigational property)

**MovieActors** (table)

- MovieId
- ActorId

Now, let's assume, we are already in the data layer (so there will be not be major change-tracking on objects except for the id's). We have the data in the movie object that needs to be persisted. If it exists, it needs to be updated, if not inserted.

Movie object (movieDTO) that's sent to DataLayer.

- MovieName
- GenreName
- SubGenreName
- DirectorName
- ProducerName
- List ActorNames

Let's also assume there are **millions** of Directors/Producers/Actors/Movies (basically huge amounts of data in each table) and the names of directors/producers/actors/movie are unique for simplicity purpose. So the logic would be, if the SubGenre exists use that, otherwise create SubGenre record. Similarly look for if Genre exists, use that otherwise create it. Likewise for the director, producer and actors.

Finally, the questions are

1. Which of these would be faster and why? (or) Are they same even while taking millions of records into consideration?
2. Is it likely to change between Sql Server and Oracle? (With oracle, I am using Devart as the provider)

**Approach 1:**

```
using (MovieDBContext context = new MovieDBContext())
        {
            Movie movie;

            movie = context.Movies.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.MovieName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (movie == null)
                movie = new Movie() { Name = movieDTO.MovieName };

            var subGenre = context.SubGenres.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.SubGenreName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (subGenre == null)
            {
                movie.SubGenre = new SubGenre() { Name = movieDTO.SubGenreName };
                // Check if Genre exists.
                var genre = context.Genres.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.GenreName).SingleOrDefault();
                if (genre == null)
                {                        
                    movie.SubGenre.Genre = new Genre() { Name = movieDTO.GenreName };
                }
                else
                {
                    movie.SubGenre.Genre = genre;
                }
            }
            else
                movie.SubGenre = subGenre;


            var director = context.Directors.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.DirectorName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (director == null)
                movie.Director = new Director() { Name = movieDTO.DirectorName };
            else
                movie.Director = director;

            var producer = context.Producers.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.ProducerName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (producer == null)
                movie.Producer = new Producer() { Name = movieDTO.ProducerName };
            else
                movie.Producer = producer;

            // I am skipping the logic of deleting all the actors if the movie is existing. 
            foreach (var name in movieDTO.Actors)
            {
                var actor = context.Actors.Where(a => a.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
                if (actor == null)
                    movie.Actors.Add(new Actor() { Name = name });
                else
                    movie.Actors.Add(actor);
            }                

            // Finally save changes. All the non-existing entities are added at once. 
            // EF is keeping track if the entity exists or not.
            context.SaveChanges(); 
        }
```

**Approach 2:**

```
using (MovieDBContext context = new MovieDBContext())
        {
            var genre = context.Genres.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.GenreName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (genre == null)
            {                      
                genre = new Genre() { Name = movieDTO.GenreName };
                context.Genres.Add(genre); // genre.Id is populated with the new id.
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var subGenre = context.SubGenre.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.SubGenreName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (subGenre == null)
            {
                subGenre = new SubGenre() { Name = movieDTO.SubGenreName };
                context.SubGenres.Add(subGenre); // subGenre.Id is populated with the new id.
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var director = context.Directors.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.DirectorName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (director == null)
            {
                director = new Director() { Name = movieDTO.DirectorName };
                context.Directors.Add(director); // director.Id is populated with the new id.
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            var producer = context.Producers.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.ProducerName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (producer == null)
            {
                producer = new Producer() { Name = movieDTO.ProducerName };
                context.Producers.Add(producer); // director.Id is populated with the new id.
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Similarly for actors, add them if they don't exist.
            foreach (var name in movieDTO.Actors)
            {
                var actor = new Actor() { Name = movieDTO.name };
                context.Actors.Add(actor); 
                context.SaveChanges();
            }       

            // Lastly movie.
            Movie movie = context.Movies.Where(a => a.Name == movieDTO.MovieName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (movie == null)
            {
                movie = new Movie() { Name = movieDTO.MovieName };
            }
            // This works for update as well.

            // The id's are added/updated instead of actual entities.
            movie.DirectorId = director.Id; 
            movie.SubGenreId = subGenre.Id; 
            movie.ProducerId = producer.Id;

            // I am skipping the logic of deleting all the actors if the movie is existing. 
            foreach (var name in movieDTO.Actors)
            {
                var actor = context.Actors.Where(a => a.Name == name).SingleOrDefault(); // Actors always exist now because we added them above.
                movie.Actors.Add(actor);
            }                

            // Finally save changes. Here only Movie object is saved as all other objects are saved earlier.
            context.SaveChanges(); 
        }
```

Comment: Is the navigation ID strictly necessary, or can you get away with just having the navigation property?  Ie, for Genre, not have GenreId?

Comment: Navigation Id is necessary.

Comment: Interesting - I don't use it myself and everything seems to work fine. :-o